# Laravel Passport createToken Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Hi I am trying to generate a token from a user object like so:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Response;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login() { 
        $content = [];
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('username'), 'password' => request('password')])){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $role = $user->roles()->first()->name;
            $content['access_token'] = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
            $status = 200;
        }
        else{
            $content['error'] = "Unauthorised";
            $content['message'] = "Your email or password are incorrect";
            $status = 401;
        }
        return response()->json($content, $status); 
    }
}
```

I am getting a 500 server error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I have the HasApiTokens on the User model and have no issues generating a token using the built in Passport routes.

Here is the first part of the Stack Trace:

```
    [2018-06-12 18:20:59] local.ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object {"userId":1,"email":"***","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object at ...vendor/laravel/passport/src/ClientRepository.php:81)
[stacktrace]
#0 ...vendor/laravel/passport/src/ClientRepository.php(81): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/Users/peterste...', 81, Array)
#1 ...vendor/laravel/passport/src/PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php(71): Laravel\\Passport\\ClientRepository->personalAccessClient()
#2 ...vendor/laravel/passport/src/HasApiTokens.php(67): Laravel\\Passport\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory->make(1, 'Token Name', Array)
#3 ...app/Http/Controllers/API/Auth/LoginController.php(16): App\\Models\\User->createToken('Token Name')
#4 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\Auth\\LoginController->login()
#5 ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('login', Array)
#7 ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\Auth\\LoginController), 'login')
#8 ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#9 ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(659): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
```

Comment: can you pls show me what you get in $role?

Comment: @SachinAghera it is a string such as 'admin'. I have commented this line out and it makes no difference

Comment: can you show detailed stack trace and error message?

Comment: $user->createToken('MyApp', $role)->accessToken

Comment: @SachinAghera Have added the first part of the stack trace

Comment: Have you run php artisan passport:install command?

Comment: @SachinAghera Yep, have auth key files and a password grant client setup

Comment: php artisan passport:client --personal

Comment: @Pedro if you are using password grant then there is another method to generate token. `$user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;` this method is for personal access tokens.

Comment: @Wellwisher That makes sense why this isn't working then. I couldn't see in the Docs how to do this with the Password Grant - do you know?

Comment: For requesting new token you have to pass  user credentials(email, password), client credentials(client id and secret), grant type...refer this url https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#requesting-password-grant-tokens

Comment: @Pedro is it resolved?

Comment: @Wellwisher nope. I know how to request a token from my JS app. But I need to know how to send back the scopes in the generated token for the user.

Comment: @Pedro after generating the token you can set the scope and other things on cookie or else you can insert the data on database.

Answer (score 4):

Might be problem in passport installation.

**Try this:** php artisan passport:install --force

Answer (score 0):

Try creating client ID and secret using the below command:
php artisan passport:client

For more details:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have already done this and have recreated these to see if that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but for the sake of those who get similar issues,

replace the 'client-id' with the value of Client ID after running

```
php artisan passport:client --personal.
```

so

```
Passport::personalAccessClientId('client-id');
```

should be replaced with `Passport::personalAccessClientId('4');` 
// where 4 is the client id generated 
// this code is inside the boot() function of the AuthServiceProvider